# how can I use colon instead of question mark in url query?

Tags: url, programming-languages

for example this image:

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BFmDUA5CcAAmcBl.jpg

then I add a color symbol to send query string:

[https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BFmDUA5CcAAmcBl.jpg:large](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BFmDUA5CcAAmcBl.jpg%3alarge)
[https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BFmDUA5CcAAmcBl.jpg:small](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BFmDUA5CcAAmcBl.jpg%3asmall)

I googled that is twitter image

what coding language can achieve this?

php? ruby on rails?

or any htaccess rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any.

It has nothing to do with programming languages, but with CGI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

The colon is however not a valid part of the CGI spec, so the server receiving the request will probably parse it in code.

Note though that the CGI spec defines '&' as separator between different variable/value pairs, which results in incorrect (X)HTML when used in `<a>` tags. This is because it doesn't define a valid entity. To remedy this, at least in PHP, you can change this separator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.output

Comment: can you provide more details/example please

Comment: Details / example of what? The documentation and links in my answer should be a good start.